# Resharper not showing add action to razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2013, resharper

I am using latest version on resharper  (v9 Update 1) on a asp.net mvc project in VS 2013. For some reason, resharper is not able to provide/highlight non existing actions in razor view. Previously it used to show an error and then provided a menu to generate the action (screenshot below).

[image]

I have tried repairing and reinstalling the resharper. Even `devenv /resetsettings` command to open Visual Studio did not help.  How to get this feature back?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. It's not even underlining the existing actions like it used to. Is this same for your case?

Answer (score 0):

Either downgrade MVC packages to 5.2.2 or install [Resharper EAP 9.1](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+9.1+EAP) 
See the issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-433112